# DataGridView not showing updated sql columns

Tags: c#, winforms, linq-to-sql, c#-4.0

My datagridview is not pulling in two new fields I added to the table in sql. I re-added the linq2sql object in visual studio with the updated table entries but I am still not able to see the two new fields when I try to add them as columns on my datagridview.

How do i refresh the datagridview so it can see these new fields?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: have you tried to rebuild the solution?

Comment: Are the columns defined explicitly or autogenerated?  If explicitly defined do you receive an error?

Comment: I tried to rebuild and it didnt work. The columns are autogenerated. I ended up just recreating the grid

Comment: Are you using dbml objects? Maybe you could delete the one you have, and drag a fresh one in?

Comment: if you try to refresh it on the form then set the dgv's datasource to null and set back..this is the easiest way to refresh the sources..

if you took your dgv from DataSource tab in vs then you need to delete and add again..if you use dataset you need to do the same for your dataset table..